# Issue related to Anaconda. It happened after i run "conda update --all". I dont know how to fix it. Can someone help to solve that issue?

Tags: anaconda

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 139, in main
    from ..activate import main as activator_main
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .base.context import ROOT_ENV_NAME, context, locate_prefix_by_name
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, ConfigurationLoadError, MapParameter,
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_round_trip_load
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\serialize.py", line 45, in <module>
    yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(odict, represent_ordereddict)
AttributeError: module 'ruamel_yaml' has no attribute 'representer'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 147, in main
    init_loggers()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 56, in init_loggers
    from ..gateways.logging import initialize_logging, set_verbosity
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..common.io import attach_stderr_handler
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .._vendor.tqdm import tqdm
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .std import tqdm, trange
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\std.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import _supports_unicode, _screen_shape_wrapper, _range, _unich, \
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\utils.py", line 43, in <module>
    colorama.init(strip=False)
AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'
```